# Linking a Windows terminal application

Tags: bash, symbolic-link

I have downloaded windows terminal application namely [pdf2djvu](https://code.google.com/p/pdf2djvu/) (equivalent of this I can't find under linux) as the name implies it converts PDF to DJVU documents (compact in size)...

I have placed the contents of pdf2djvu in my wine 'Program Files' directory now I can easily use this via

```
cd "/home/usama/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/pdf2djvu-0.7.14" wine
pdf2djvu.exe -o sample.djvu -v pdffile2convert.pdf
```

Now its laborious...I just want to create a link in /usr/bin to use pdf2djvu as native linux executable. My following attempts has thus far failed

1] Create a bash file & linking it to /usr/bin

```
#!/bin/bash
wine "/home/usama/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/pdf2djvu-0.7.14/pdf2djvu.exe"
```

2] Using autokey phrase placement

```
wine "/home/usama/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/pdf2djvu-0.7.14/pdf2djvu.exe" -o ~/documents/sample.djvu -v ""
```

In either case terminal reports

> No input file specified

Comment: Have you tried compiling this one? : https://code.google.com/p/pdf2djvu/downloads/detail?name=pdf2djvu_0.7.17.tar.gz&can=2&q= . Also, what about [this](http://code.google.com/p/pdf2djvu/downloads/detail?name=pdf2djvu_0.5.8_i386.deb&can=4&q=) and [this](http://pkgs.org/ubuntu-12.04/ubuntu-universe-amd64/pdf2djvu_0.7.11-1build1_amd64.deb.html) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try PDF to DjVu converter.  pdf2djvu creates DjVu files from PDF files.  Its available in Ubuntu Apps.

To install, just click [**pdf2djvu** [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pdf2djvu/).

Or

just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install pdf2djvu
```